# How to convert sql query to list?

Tags: python-3.x, list

I am trying to convert my sql query output into a list to look a certain way.

Here is my code:

```
def get_sf_metadata():

    import sqlite3
    #Tables I want to be dynamically created
    table_names=['AcceptedEventRelation','Asset', 'Book']

    #SQLIte Connection
    conn = sqlite3.connect('aaa_test.db')
    c = conn.cursor()

    #select the metadata table records
    c.execute("select  name, type from sf_field_metadata1  limit 10 ")
    print(list(c))


get_sf_metadata()
```

Here is my output:

```
[('Id', 'id'), ('RelationId', 'reference'), ('EventId', 'reference')]
```

Is there any way to make the output looks like this:

```
[Id id, RelationId reference, EventId  reference]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try

```
print(["{} {}".format(i[0], i[1]) for i in list(c)])
```

That will print you

```
['Id id', 'RelationId reference', 'EventId reference']
```

Comment: my hero, my savior